# Komodo edit -auto-complete chained jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, komodo, komodoedit

How do you get code hinting/completion for chained functions in Komodo edit.

I had it working in Komodo Edit 5, but I lost the ability when I upgraded to ver 6. Now it gives me code hinting for the first function, then any chained functions only give basic javascript code hinting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out it was a bug in Komodo Edit 6.0/6.0.1. The issue was fixed in 6.0.3 which was released a few days ago.